# Multisite configuration for multiple domains

Tags: multisite, domain

I have a multisite installation running fine with two sites. I can access both of them with no problems using the urls mydomain.com/site1 and mydomain.com/site2.

The problem is that I need to configure my site1 to be accessed from an url of another domain, ex: anotherdomain.com

How can I achieve this? I changed my site's URL on the Network dashboard to anotherdomain.com and it's dns pointing to mydomain.com. It didn't work, my main site is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress supports **Domain Mapping**.

WordPress multisite subsites may be mapped to a non-network top-level domain. This means a site created as subsite1.networkdomain.com, can be mapped to show as domain.com. This also works for subdirectory sites, so networkdomain.com/subsite1 can also appear at domain.com. Before setting up domain mapping, make sure your network has been correctly set up, and subsites can be created without issues.

Before WordPress 4.5, domain mapping requires a domain mapping plugin like WordPress MU Domain Mapping.

In WordPress 4.5+, domain mapping is a native feature.

---

Full details and tutorial can be find here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping

Comment: Hmm, this is exactly what I did but I get redirected to the multisite's main site. Maybe there's something wrong with my .htaccess.